# Setting navigation bar color in UITableViewController.

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a fairly simple application with a `UITableViewController` and a `UINavigationController`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    OverviewTableViewController *overview = [[OverviewTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OverviewTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:overview];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In my `OverviewTableViewController` I tried setting a color for the navigation bar like this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = TRUE;
```

I know I can do it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like this:

```
nav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
nav.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

How can I do this in my `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OverviewTableViewController`'s viewDidLoad

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UIColor *bg = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:bg];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, although the translucent doesn't seem to be working, but I think that's unrelated to this question.

Comment: Yup.. just setting the bar style to black.
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack]?

edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `OverviewTableViewController`, you can refer to the navigationController using `self.navigationController`.

So, you can do with the code below.

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
nav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
nav.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```